# MySQLi returns 0 rows when query is a variable

Tags: php, database, mysqli

My problem is really simple - I use mysqli to connect my script with database, but when I try to execute SELECT statement - it returns 0 rows when I use variable (for ex. $abc) as a query string...

I use this function to create query:

```
function get($array) {
    $select = $array['select'];
    $from = '`' .$array['from'] . '`';
    $fetch = $array['fetch'];

    $query_text = "SELECT " . $select . " FROM " . $from;
    if(array_key_exists('where', $array)) {
        $where = $array['where'];
        $query_text .= " WHERE " . $where;
    }

    if(array_key_exists('order', $array)) {
        $order = $array['order'];
        if(!empty($order)){
            $query_text .= " ORDER " . $order;
        }
    }


    $result = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, $query_text);
    echo $result->num_rows;
}
```

I'm using it by doing this:

```
$id = 1; // just for the example.
$query = get(array('select' => '*', 'from' => 'something', 'where' => 'id = ' . $id . '', 'fetch' => false);
```

And when I do that ($query = get(...)) then it shows 0 (because it didn't found any row), and if I do that in get() function:

```
function get($array) {
    [...]
    $result = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "SELECT * FROM something WHERE id = 1"); // It's the same query.
}
```

Then it shows 1 - because it found 1 row!

These two queries are identical but returns 0 (that one from variable) and 1 row (that one written by me).
How is it possible?

Comment: What do you see if you echo `$query_text` before you use it? Is there any errors? (you can check using `mysqli_error`)

Comment: @Jim: SELECT * FROM something WHERE id = 1 <- query, 
<- no error, 
0 <- 0 rows found

Comment: That query doesn't look like it came from the `get` function. The get function encloses `something` in `. Are you sure there is an entry in the database?

Comment: take a `exit($query_text);` just before `$result = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, $query_text);` and see what it prints

Comment: @Jim: Yeah, I didn't saw it - my friend is trying to help me too, and he deleted these ` from code - I added them again, it's still not working.

@Saqueib:
exit($query_text); shows:
SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE id = 1

Comment: I am not sure about var `$prefix`  it seams out of scope

Comment: @Saqueib I changed get() function a bit meantime, so it doesn't use '$prefix' variable - it's the only change obviously.

Comment: this function is working and its building query `SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE id = 1` i think problem is somewhere else, show some more code